# Slick2d using anti-aliasing with Animations/Images

Tags: java, opengl, antialiasing, slick2d, artifacts

I'm using slick2d to render an Animation, but using anti-aliasing

Without AA, the movement is choppy, as one would expect for something without AA.
I turn on AA in my game's preRenderState with:

```
g.setAntiAlias(true);
```

This leads to:

[image: Image with graphical glitch]

Note the diagonal line in the center, presumably caused by the two triangles that render the rectangle not meeting precicely. How can I remove that while still using AA to smooth my movement? I found http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=27313.0 but the solution was "remove AA" which I am reluctant to do.

Comment: Those white lines are not rasterization errors if that is what you are thinking, quite the contrary. They will go away if you use the proper blend function _(see my answer for more details)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This looks suspiciously like artifacts due to `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH`.

When you use that (deprecated) functionality, you are expected to draw all opaque geometry with blending enabled and the blend function: `GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE`. Failure to do so produces white outlines on most contours (aliased edges, basically).

> #### [Chapter 6](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter06.html) of the OpenGL Redbook states:
>
> > Now you need to blend overlapping edges appropriately. First, turn off the depth buffer so that you have control over how overlapping pixels are drawn. Then set the blending factors to `GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE` (source) and `GL_ONE` (destination). With this specialized blending function, the final color is the sum of the destination color and the scaled source color; the scale factor is the smaller of either the incoming source alpha value or one minus the destination alpha value.
> >
> > This means that for a pixel with a large alpha value, successive incoming pixels have little effect on the final color because one minus the destination alpha is almost zero. With this method, a pixel on the edge of a polygon might be blended eventually with the colors from another polygon that's drawn later. Finally, you need to sort all the polygons in your scene so that they're ordered from front to back before drawing them.

That is a lot of work that almost nobody does correctly when they try to enable `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH`.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try it out when I get the chance, thanks! Too bad there isn't a way to do it from within slick2d itself, but I suppose this could work.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you enable anti-aliasing in Slick2D, it should look like this.

```
g.setAntiAlias(true);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL11.GL_ONE);
```

Basically same as Andon's answer, but with code that should solve the problem.

Note that with this whatever you draw first will be on top, rather than what you draw last. So you may need to reverse rendering order.